# What module should I install for php?

Tags: configuration

I am trying to import a rule for facebook autopost in Configuration>Workflow>Rules, but after I click import button, I receive the error message below. I don't know which php module I have to install. I have searched on drupal site but I don't figure out which module I have to install.

Regards,

[image]

Comment: php module comes with drupal 7 core. you just need to enable it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should enable PHP Filter modules under *CORE* . Go to /admin/modules and find PHP Filter module and enable

[image]

It allows embedded PHP code to be evaluated